# Combine two loops in Python- continue calculation based on the result of first loop

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
seed(4)
for _ in range(20):
 value = randint(0, 100)
 print(value, end=',' )

for n in [value]:

    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(df3_X1,df3_Y1, test_size=0.25, random_state=n)

 params = {'n_estimators': 500,
          'max_depth': 4,
          'min_samples_split': 5,
          'learning_rate': 0.01,
          'loss': 'ls'}
    estimators = [

    ('svr', make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),

     SVR(kernel='rbf',C=0.6))),
    ('gb', GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0))
    ]

    stack = StackingRegressor(estimators=estimators,final_estimator= RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,

    random_state=0))
    Final_model = stack.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = Final_model.predict(X_test)
    y_bar = y_test.mean()
    ss_tot = ((y_test-y_bar)**2).sum()
    ss_res = ((y_test-predictions)**2).sum()
    r2_score = 1 - (ss_res/ss_tot)
    print(n,'r2_score is',r2_score)
print('The for loop is complete!')
```

The output is:

```
30,38,13,92,50,61,19,11,8,2,51,70,37,97,7,28,66,68,46,35,35 r2_score is -9.856906951871588
```

But I want to obtain r2_score for all numbers in value including 30,38,13,92,50,61,19,11,8,2,51,70,37,97,7,28,66,68,46,35

But the script only calculate r2_score for last number in value which 35.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the point of `for n in [value]`?  The list has exactly one element, so why even have a loop at all?

Comment: Consistent indentation isn't a suggestion in Python. It's a requirement.

Comment: "But I want to obtain r2_score for all numbers in value" - there are two problems here. The first problem is that `value` **isn't something that has numbers in it** - it's just a **single number**. Please see the linked duplicate in order to understand how to set up `value` properly. The second problem is that `for n in [value]:` does not look at the contents of `value`; it looks at the contents of `[value]` - that is, a list that has just `value` in it. If you wrote `for n in value:` before and got an error, the problem is that you tried to fix it **without properly understanding the cause**.

Answer (score -2):

```
for _ in range(20):
 value = randint(0, 100)
 print(value, end=',' )
```

This `for` loop only contains two lines of code.

Your further code that prints the r2_score is NOT part of this loop.

Perhaps you meant to indent all of the further code so it is part of this loop?

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer as it's making guesses as to the nature of the problem and seeking clarification.

Comment: @Chris I would say that the first sentence is definitely an answer to the question "What am I doing wrong"?  And the last sentence is a suggestion for how to fix it.

Comment: It seems very clear to me that the goal was to create a list explicitly and then iterate over it in a separate loop. Hence the question text, "r2_score for all numbers in value". Aside from that, issues like this can't realistically make questions worth answering. Once properly refined, they are all duplicates.